# Reading individual digits from a number stored in a file

Tags: c

I'm currently working through Project Euler problems as a way of learning C and I'm having trouble with problem #8, the actual maths and main bit of program is fine but the method requires reading individual digits from a large (1000 digit) number, which I put in a file.

The code below is for a test case, where my file "test.txt" is the number "123456789". What I am trying to do is print out each digit on a separate line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while(c != EOF)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%i\n", c);      

    }

    fclose(fp);

}
```

When I run this code, I get the output

```
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
10
-1
```

I have a hunch I am missing something really simple from my code and I would expect it is in the fgetc bit. If this is the case, what would be a better function to use and I'm also curious of why I get such a weird output - when I try it with my 1000 digit number I find a similar pattern with numbers around 49 to high 50s being output almost cyclically. Please bear in mind I am only a beginner with C, cheers.

Comment: Holy duplicated answers, Batman.

Comment: Its the ascii codes and -1 is the end of the file. Read as char when you use fgetc.

Comment: @subirkumarsao - `fgetc` returns an `int`, so what Josh is doing is correct.

Comment: @Mike in this case if he reads as int then he will get ascii characters. But he reads as char then he will directly get the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the digits:

```
48 = '0'
49 = '1'
50 = '2'
```

etc. They're in that format because they're characters stored in a text file which represent integer digits.

You need to print:

```
if((48 <= c) && (c <= 57))
  printf("%d\n", c - '0');
```

Note: You'll want that `if` check because the 10 is a newline and the -1 is EOF, you're printing more then you wanted.

Of course there are lots of ways to do this if check:

```
if(('0' <= c) && (c <= '9'))
```

or

```
if(isdigit(c))
```

The point is simply that you need to check if you only want digits.

Comment: Wouldn't '0', '9' be clearer than hard-coded values?  `if (isdigit(c))` might be clearer still

Comment: @simonc - "clearer" to whom? :) I do see your point however, so I've updated to note there are lots of ways to do this, whichever OP can read best is the best way to go. I just like checking ints against int.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%i\n", c);` prints the [ascii character code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of each number.

The code below checks whether each character is a digit then prints either the digit (by subtracting the character code for 0) or a warning if non-numeric content is encountered:

```
while(c != EOF) {
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        printf("%i\n", c-'0');
    }
    else {
        printf(" non-numeric digit (%i)\n", c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are printing the ASCII values of the numbers. Here is the snippet from the ASCII table on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII):

```
Dec Hex Glyph
48  30  0
49  31  1
50  32  2
51  33  3
52  34  4
53  35  5
54  36  6
55  37  7
56  38  8
57  39  9
```

The `10` and `-1` you get at the end are a newline and the `EOF`.

When you read text in from a file it is giving you the ASCII character data, so you need to subtract the offset for the character '0' from the values to get numbers instead:

```
printf("%d\n", c - '0');
```

Note that you can use the `'0'` character directly in the subtraction because the compiler will convert it to the appropriate number for you. It is better to use '`'0'` instead of just subtracting 48 because it is clearer what you are trying to do, and also because of potentially different character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

you're printing the ASCII value of each number and also printing the EOF because you check before reading and not after:

```
while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%i\n", c-'0');
}
```